# Erro ao ordenar GridView com coluna de linha vazia

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Está dando um erro aqui que eu não estou sabendo contornar, como meu programa lê um site, algumas vezes o site pode fugir do padrão e acabar saindo umas coisas vazias, então quando meu GridView tenta ordenar, se tiver algum item vazio pelo visto ele está bugando...

Aqui oque está acontecendo:
[image]

Comment: Se você colocar o código talvez alguém que entenda possa te ajudar. Do jeito que está fica difícil adivinhar seu problema.

Comment: Forneça mais detalhes para podermos analisar o problema

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta não esta clara o suficiente, então vou chuta por cima o que possa esta acontecendo baseado no seu erro.

Ou seja, [interface IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Essa interface é implementada por tipos cujos valores podem ser ordenados ou classificados.***Ele requer que os tipos de implementação definem um único método, [CompareTo(Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx)***, que indica se a posição da instância atual na ordem de classificação é antes, depois, ou o mesmo que um segundo objeto do mesmo tipo.

A  implementação da instância IComparable é chamada automaticamente por métodos, como [Array.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.array.sort(v=vs.110).aspx) e [ArrayList.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/8k6e334t(v=vs.110).aspx).

A implementação de CompareTo(Object) método deve retornar um Int32 que tem um dos três valores, conforme mostrado na tabela a seguir

*Resumindo seu objeto deve ser nulo e não implementa a **interface IComparable** e não pode ser comparado com o objeto da instância atual.*